# Asked a raise, how long should I wait to hear back?

Tags: performance-reviews, raise

Premise: The company I work for doesn't have an automatic salary raise policy (like x% each year)

During my last yearly review I asked for a raise to my superior (I felt was the appropriate time, the review is a talk, nothing written, we simply discuss how was the previous year and future plans) and he asked me for a number and I gave to him.

After he told me that he will discuss with his superior and back to me regarding my raise request.

How long should I wait before reminding him again about my request?

Answer (score 1):

Do not wait for your manager to get back to you. Politely and respectfully remind him/her in your weekly 1:1 meeting or in private otherwise. Managers usually have lots on their plate and often focus on the "squeaky wheel".

Be prepared for your manager to say no. If so, do not get angry or resentful - raises are often determined by budget decisions than performance. Instead, ask your boss what you would need to do to get a raise then deliver on that. If the company consistently does not offer raises, other companies do and money is important to you then consider leaving and joining a company that offers better pay.

Comment: thank you for your answer, we don't do 1:1 meetings expect the yearly reviews or booked meetings with subject prearranged. I trust my superior but it's his job to take care of my request, and I'm a person that doesn't like to reminder others that they need to do their job. So my question was more: which is the amount of time I can wait so I can be pretty sure he forgot my request?

Comment: With respect @user35912, I think you are looking at this the wrong way. While your manager might be responsible for facilitating the raise, it is likely a minute part of a much bigger role. Perhaps there are cultural differences but I do not see this as "reminding others that they need to do their job", more impressing upon him/her how important this is to him and how it would ensure his/her team feels valued.

Comment: I didn't write or intend that my superior need to facilitate the raise or support me when he will discuss with his superior. But If I make an official request to my superior the minimum that I ask is to get a reply. It's the same as asking to have the week X as holiday, he can reply something like "I will look into and back to you", my problem is after how many days I can remind him of my request (because he forgot or his superior was not available). Of course I can't ask him the day after and of course I can't wait the next yearly review to get a reply. I hope I explained myself

Comment: @user35912 Ask him after a week. It's time enough where he's had a chance to look into it if he didn't forget, yet it doesn't seem too pushy. You obviously don't want to go up to him every day because that'll harbor resentment, but you do want to remind him if he forgot/let him know that you're not willing to simply quiet down about it if he ignores you. Depending on his reply at that point you can decide what to do from there. Keep in mind that he may be busy so if he's short about it don't take it personally. In another week I would bring it up again if he hasn't said anything.

Comment: @zfrisch thanks for your comment, you understood what I meant

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible to give a hard number as it will greatly depend on company culture.  If he only needs to consult his superior the time frame is very different from if he needs to get 5 people to sign off on it.  The only way to know what the delay is is to ask.

Wait long enough that he will have had a chance to talk with his superior.  How long this is will again depend on company culture.  For example this meeting will take longer to happen if there is a big time zone difference.

Comment: thanks for your answer, especially for the part "if he needs to get 5 people to sign off on it". I'm not so familiar with the company structure so I don't know currently if other people will be involved than my superior and his superior.

Answer (score 1):

Why not ask your boss this question?  That seems the more sensible approach.

> Hey boss, I was wondering when I might expect an answer about the
>   raise?

Then rather than a bunch of random internet people guessing you'll have an actionable answer to work from.

Comment: probably you didn't understand the meaning of my question. I will ask that phrase to my superior, the problem is "when"

Comment: @user35912: I'd approach the boss if I haven't heard anything in a week.